# Pyspark: GroupBy multiple columns and calculate group number

Tags: python, pyspark, group-by, bigdata

I have a dataframe like:

```
id Name Rank Course
1  S1   21   Physics
2  S2   22   Chemistry
3  S3   24   Math
4  S2   22   English
5  S2   22   Social
6  S1   21   Geography
```

I want to group this dataset over Name, Rank and calculate group number. In pandas, I can easily do:

```
df['ngrp'] = df.groupby(['Name', 'Rank']).ngroup()
```

After computing the above, I get the following output:

```
id Name Rank Course     ngrp
1  S1   21   Physics    0
6  S1   22   Geography  0
2  S2   22   Chemistry  1
4  S2   22   English    1
5  S2   23   Social     1
3  S3   24   Math       2
```

Is there a method in Pyspark that will achieve the same output? I tried the following, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
w = Window.partitionBy(['Name', 'Rank'])
df.select(['Name', 'Rank'], ['Course'], f.count(['Name', 'Rank']).over(w).alias('ngroup')).show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can opt for [DENSE_RANK](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.dense_rank.html#:%7E:text=Window%20function%3A%20returns%20the%20rank,sequence%20when%20there%20are%20ties.) -

#### Data Preparation

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
id,Name,Rank,Course
1,S1,21,Physics
2,S2,22,Chemistry
3,S3,24,Math
4,S2,22,English
5,S2,22,Social
6,S1,21,Geography
"""),delimiter=',')

sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(df)

sparkDF.show()
+---+----+----+---------+
| id|Name|Rank|   Course|
+---+----+----+---------+
|  1|  S1|  21|  Physics|
|  2|  S2|  22|Chemistry|
|  3|  S3|  24|     Math|
|  4|  S2|  22|  English|
|  5|  S2|  22|   Social|
|  6|  S1|  21|Geography|
+---+----+----+---------+
```

#### Dense Rank

```
window = Window.orderBy(['Name','Rank'])

sparkDF = sparkDF.withColumn('ngroup',F.dense_rank().over(window) - 1)

sparkDF.orderBy(['Name','ngroup']).show()

+---+----+----+---------+------+
| id|Name|Rank|   Course|ngroup|
+---+----+----+---------+------+
|  6|  S1|  21|Geography|     0|
|  1|  S1|  21|  Physics|     0|
|  4|  S2|  22|  English|     1|
|  2|  S2|  22|Chemistry|     1|
|  5|  S2|  22|   Social|     1|
|  3|  S3|  24|     Math|     2|
+---+----+----+---------+------+
```

#### Dense Rank - SparkSQL

```
sql.sql("""
SELECT
    ID,
    NAME,
    RANK,
    COURSE,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY NAME,RANK) - 1 as NGROUP
FROM TB1
""").show()

+---+----+----+---------+------+
| ID|NAME|RANK|   COURSE|NGROUP|
+---+----+----+---------+------+
|  1|  S1|  21|  Physics|     0|
|  6|  S1|  21|Geography|     0|
|  2|  S2|  22|Chemistry|     1|
|  4|  S2|  22|  English|     1|
|  5|  S2|  22|   Social|     1|
|  3|  S3|  24|     Math|     2|
+---+----+----+---------+------+
```